# Disabling browser autocomplete on Material-UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using Material UI's country select (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#country-select). I have an ongoing issue that when the user clicks into the input, the browser autocomplete pop up blocks the view of country options. I've tried my best to turn autocomplete to off but with no joy. Can anyone advise a possible workaround?

Have tried the 3 commonly suggested fixes:

`autoComplete="off"`

`autoComplete="no"`

`autoComplete="new-password"`

```
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select"
      options={options}
      classes={{
        option: classes.option,
      }}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue(field.name, value.label)}
      onOpen={field.onBlur}
      renderOption={(option) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <span>{countryToFlag(option.code)}</span>
          {option.label}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label={props.label}
          name={props.name}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          variant="outlined"
          helperText={_renderErrorText()}
          error={hasError}
          autoComplete="off"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

AutoComplete should be on rendered Input by material-ui, not the TextField wrapper. So you should do something like that:

```
<TextField
    {...params}
    label={props.label}
    name={props.name}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    variant="outlined"
    helperText={_renderErrorText()}
    error={hasError}
    inputProps={{
        autoComplete: 'new-password',
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

```
autoComplete="chrome-off"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for Chrome and Edge. However, Firefox and Opera are still offering to save passwords. Do you know a solution for them as well?